# Spring Data + SQL Server remove schema name from entity class

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Is there anyway to remove schema from class annotation and put it in application.properties file so that if for different environment there is different schema I can control from properties file.

NOTE: I am using MS-SQL Server database.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TRANSACTIONS", schema="schema_name")
public class Transaction implements Serializable {
```

I tried below, but non of these works for me.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.default_schema=schema_name
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema_name
hibernate.default_schema=schema_name
spring.hibernate.default_schema=schema_name
```

Comment: @Jiger Did you find any solution for the problem ??

Answer (score 2):

You should specify shcema name in jdbc url as below .

```
jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress:port;database=DBName;schema=SCHEMANAME;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false
```

Comment: The above solution is not working, it is still throwing Invalid Object name error.

Answer (score 0):

Before going forward, make sure you have done the following:
Added the following Dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Now all you need to do is specify the required credentials of your MySQL database in application.propeties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SchemaName? 
useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root
```

Since you have specified your schema name in spring.datasource.url, you don't need to do so anywhere again.

Finally, you can now use the Model Class(@Entity) without specifying schema, like the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class EmployeeInfo {
@Id
@Column(name = "`EMPLOYEE_NUMBER`")
private int empid;

@Column(name = "`EMPLOYEE_NAME`")
private String empname;
```